# No audio from built-in speakers in Recalbox - 1UP Pi-Boy XL

Tags: audio, recalbox

I recently picked up a 1UP Pi-Boy XL, which runs Recalbox (v6.1.1-Dragonblaze). The built-in speakers only make sound during the Recalbox loading screen, but then refuse to play audio.  Within Recalbox, the audio options only allow selection between auto/HDMI/Headphone.  HDMI and headphone work as expected.  Auto will output to headphones when I plug them in, but otherwise, no sound comes from the built-in speakers.  Recalbox logs don't seem to have anything specific to guide me.

Here are the sound cards:

```
/recalbox/share/system$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835_alsa - bcm2835 ALSA
                      bcm2835 ALSA
```

Given that, I ran the aadebug detailed here (https://alsa.opensrc.org/Aadebug)
And the output is here:

```
ALSA Audio Debug v0.2.0 - Sun Dec 15 02:32:44 CET 2019
http://alsa.opensrc.org/aadebug
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.txt

Kernel ----------------------------------------------------
Linux RECALBOX 4.14.62-v7 #1 SMP Wed Nov 13 12:29:03 CET 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k4.14.62-v7.

Loaded Modules --------------------------------------------
./aadebug: line 12: lsmod: command not found
./aadebug: line 13: lsmod: command not found

Proc Asound -----------------------------------------------
 0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835_alsa - bcm2835 ALSA
                      bcm2835 ALSA
cat: can't open '/proc/asound/hwdep': No such file or directory
cat: can't open '/proc/asound/seq/clients': No such file or directory
  0: [ 0]   : control
 16: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
 17: [ 0- 1]: digital audio playback
 33:        : timer
00-00: bcm2835 ALSA : bcm2835 ALSA : playback 7
00-01: bcm2835 ALSA : bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI : playback 1

Dev Snd ---------------------------------------------------
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            60 Jan  1  1980 by-path
crw-rw----    1 root     audio     116,   0 Jan  1  1980 controlC0
crw-rw----    1 root     audio     116,  16 Jan  1  1980 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----    1 root     audio     116,  17 Jan  1  1980 pcmC0D1p
crw-rw----    1 root     audio     116,  33 Jan  1  1980 timer
lspci: /sys/bus/pci/devices: No such file or directory

CPU -------------------------------------------------------
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)

RAM -------------------------------------------------------
MemTotal:         571864 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB

Hardware --------------------------------------------------

Interupts -------------------------------------------------
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
 16:          0          0          0          0  bcm2836-timer   0 Edge      arch_timer
 17:   16267558    8674738   17805748    3431072  bcm2836-timer   1 Edge      arch_timer
 21:          0          0          0          0  bcm2836-pmu   9 Edge      arm-pmu
 23:      12496          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level   1 Edge      3f00b880.mailbox
 24:    4118696          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level   2 Edge      VCHIQ doorbell
 46:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  48 Edge      bcm2708_fb dma
 48:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  50 Edge      DMA IRQ
 50:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  52 Edge      DMA IRQ
 51:        216          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  53 Edge      DMA IRQ
 54:       7490          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  56 Edge      DMA IRQ
 59:          0          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  61 Edge      bcm2835-auxirq
 62:   55272120          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  64 Edge      dwc_otg, dwc_otg_pcd, dwc_otg_hcd:usb1
 86:       2184          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  88 Edge      mmc0
 87:       4747          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  89 Edge      uart-pl011
 92:     516855          0          0          0  ARMCTRL-level  94 Edge      mmc1
FIQ:              usb_fiq
IPI0:          0          0          0          0  CPU wakeup interrupts
IPI1:          0          0          0          0  Timer broadcast interrupts
IPI2:      42671     142159     890071      75797  Rescheduling interrupts
IPI3:          6          8          9          6  Function call interrupts
IPI4:          0          0          0          0  CPU stop interrupts
IPI5:          0          0          0          0  IRQ work interrupts
IPI6:          0          0          0          0  completion interrupts
Err:          0
```

Any bright ideas?  I'm not sure if it ever worked -- the first thing I did when I got my XL was update recalbox, and I'm not sure I ever tested the onboard audio.  But it DOES play during the startup sequence.  Thanks!